# Best machine learning approach for instance prediction in a clinical multidimensional time series?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, mixed-model, biostatistics

My dataset comprises 130 instances of sudden unexpected clinical deterioration across 100 hospital inpatients. Time series data for 12 physiological features measured at typically 1-4 hourly intervals are available for 48 hours prior to each instance. A separate time series of clinical events (seizures) occuring over the same 48 hour period, with features including time of occurrence and duration is available for a subset of patients. The total number of datapoints is around 10,000-20,000. A set of fixed characteristics for each patient can also be incorporated (up to 20 additional features).

The objective is to develop a prediction tool, or real time clinical decision support system, to anticipate and prevent future instances of deterioration before they occur. A secondary objective is to predict severe instances, defined as required for admission to the intensive care unit following the deterioration (around one third of instances).

Questions

1. Is machine learning a feasible approach in a dataset of this relatively modest size? Some 'shallow methods' that I have read about include kernel support vectors, k nearest neighbour. Are there others more applicable to this dataset?
2. What packages are available to apply these methods in R?
3. As my features comprise cardiorespiratory and neurological observations, normal values of which vary significantly by age, would it be prudent to convert these to z scores for age as a first step of data processing?
4. What graphical tools might be employed to present the data, and any prediction model that can be developed from it, to a clinical (i.e. non-statistically expert) audience?

Many thanks for taking the time to read and respond to this question from a first-time poster!

Comment: Have you considered survival type analysis?
 http://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Analysis%20intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply- however I'm not sure if survival analysis applies, as every patient has a deterioration event- there are no controls or "survivors" (of course there are survivors in the sense of mortality, but not in the sense of surviving event free)

Comment: And the time to event is the same for every patient (48 hours of observations preceding the event)